# UnravellingAngularJs 1.5 trying to configure Node fails

Tags: angularjs, node.js, server

i started reading Unraveling AngularJS 1.5 to learn something related to Angular, and at the beginning of the book the author sugest to install node, i did it, when i run Node on the cmd it shows me that it was installed, then he says to go to the chapter01, i did it with the cd command, and write npm install to install the package.json in this step i get some warnings like this:

> npm WARN package.json UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm WARN package.json UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 No Readme data.

I think the problem has nothing to do with that, but when i follow the next step, that is to go to the chapter01 -> live-server-test with cd, then writing npm start, it just doesnt work here is the errors that i get:

> C:\Users\filipe\Desktop\Samples\Chapter01\live-server-test>npm start
>
> UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 start C:\Users\filipe\Desktop\Samples\Chapter01\liv
>   e-server-test
>   npm run live
>
> UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 live C:\Users\filipe\Desktop\Samples\Chapter01\live
>   -server-test
>   live-server
>
> 'live-server' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo,
>   programa operacional ou ficheiro batch.
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "live" npm ERR! node v4.4.7
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 live: `live-server` npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 live script
>   'live-server'. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the
>   UnravelingAngular1.5 package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR!
>   Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!
>   live-server npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue
>   for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs UnravelingAngular1.5 npm
>   ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR!
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls UnravelingAngular1.5 npm ERR! There is
>   likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\filipe\Desktop\Samples\Chapter01\live-server-test\npm-debu
>   g.log
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start" npm ERR! node v4.4.7 npm
>   ERR! npm  v2.15.8 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 start: `npm run live` npm ERR! Exit status
>   1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the UnravelingAngular1.5@1.0.0 start
>   script 'npm run live'. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the
>   UnravelingAngular1.5 package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR!
>   Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     npm run
>   live npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs UnravelingAngular1.5 npm ERR! Or
>   if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   npm owner ls UnravelingAngular1.5 npm ERR! There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\filipe\Desktop\Samples\Chapter01\live-server-test\npm-debu
>   g.log

Need a bit help here dont know what is happening :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At *chapter01 -> live-server-test with cd* 
just run `npm install` there and then `npm start`. It would work.
By your description it seems `live-server-test` has some packages itself.

Good luck

Comment: you saved my day, im kinda newbie with this server configuration and things related stuff :D

Comment: Glad I could help. :)